# How to add header elements in Spring Integration-WS?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

My request is like

```
<soapenv:Header>
      <tns:SubHeader>
         <tns:version>xyz</tns:version>

      </tns:SubHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
```

I am calling this using Spring-WS.
Here how can i set  subheader `(<tns:SubHeader>)` value?

My handler method is like

```
SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest();
SoapHeader sh = soapMessage.getSoapHeader();
sh.addHeaderElement(new QName("http://test.com/v2", "SubHeader","tns"));
```

Using this i can  add `<tns:SubHeader>` in `<soapenv:Header>` .
How can i add `<tns:version>xyz</tns:version>` in this request??

Answer (score 1):

You can create simple SOAP headers using `mapped-request-headers`

```
<ws:outbound-gateway uri="http://blah/blah"
    mapped-request-headers="foo" />
```

.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header foo="bar"/>
...
```

For anything more sophisticated I believe you'd need to use a custom message factory, or perhaps a client interceptor to manipulate the message.

Comment: Thanks@Gary.. Can u help on how to implement using custom message factory?

Comment: The interceptor route is probably much easier, but I've not done it myself; I'd have to figure it out just as much as you would.

Answer (score 1):

Use interceptor such:

```
<int-ws:outbound-gateway
        uri="${services.mobileApprove}" request-channel="mobileApproveService"
        message-sender="mobileApproveMessageSender" 
        interceptor="soapHeaderElementAdder"/>
```

And here is a bean implementation: (**soapHeaderElementAdder** is an id reference to a *spring bean*)

```
public class
    UserContextSoapElementAdder implements org.springframework.ws.client.support.interceptor.ClientInterceptor {


Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserContextSoapElementAdder.class);

@Override
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
    try {
        Object si = messageContext.getProperty("si");

        SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest();

        SoapHeader sh = soapMessage.getSoapHeader();

        SoapHeaderElement soapHeaderInformation = sh.addHeaderElement(new QName("http://harmoni-integration.yamanyar.com.tr", "si",
                ""));


        //work with soapHeaderInformation 



    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Cannot add user context soap header!", e);
    }


    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
    return true;
}
```

}